# Void is an invalid type for the method onCreate and onClick?

Tags: java, android

```
}
@Override
public void finish(){
    super.finish();
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
    Button btnStartMinorActivity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnStartMinorActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartAnotherActivity);

        btnStartMinorActivity.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent inent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);

        // calling an activity using <intent-filter> action name 
        //  Intent inent = new Intent("com.hmkcode.android.ANOTHER_ACTIVITY");

        startActivity(inent);
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? I have my activity_my.xml file in order. The tutorial for adding multiple activities is unclear at times and doesn't address this issue.

Comment: You can't have a method inside a method in Java.

Comment: Indeed - it looks like you've basically forgotten to close the `finish` method.

Comment: "Method within methods" are not allowed in Java. So either this is about a simple typo, or the OP tried to actually have  methods inside methods. Which is simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Move this methods onCreate() and onClick() outside of finish() method and i think it will be ok. Also Button btnStartMinorActivity; should be delared outside of method i think.